# How can I enable highlighting such that all Python variables use the same color?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, python

When I was using VSCode as my main code editor, many extensions like [**The One Dark Pro theme**](https://binaryify.github.io/OneDark-Pro/#/) offered variable highlighting.

This is not [**Semantic highlighting**](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview), where each variable is assigned its own unique color, repeated through each reference; I want all my variables to have 1 unique color. For example, all variables should be red.

I have tried using [**NeoVim**](https://neovim.io/) with the [**One Dark Pro NVIM**](https://github.com/olimorris/onedarkpro.nvim) plugin, but even that did not fix my problem; variable color is completely ignored.

Is there a way to have variable highlighting for Vim?

Comment: You should wait until you are proficient with Vim to decide if switching is actually worthwhile or not.

Comment: Learning Python, Vim and a bunch of plugins at the same time is quite a challenge. Consider learning *one* new thing at a time. At least wait until you feel comfortable with the Vim fundamentals before you heap plugins on top.

Answer (score 0):

About Semantic highlighting for Neovim I would advice you to look at:

- [treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) together with
- [hlargs.nvim](https://github.com/m-demare/hlargs.nvim) or [semshi](https://github.com/numirias/semshi)

With [hlargs.nvim](https://github.com/m-demare/hlargs.nvim):

[image]

With [semshi](https://github.com/numirias/semshi):

[image]

Remark: [semshi](https://github.com/numirias/semshi) is specific to Python code where [hlargs.nvim](https://github.com/m-demare/hlargs.nvim) applies to other language too.

Comment: Pardon me sir/madam, would you also please tell me about the plugin you use for enhancing the space guide?

Comment: Feel free to ask a specific question about that. If you mean displaying the space it is a standard feature of Vim/Neovim: `:set listchars+=space:.`, `:set list` to add to your `init.vim`.